# Is there a way to play tutorials you have skipped?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

I skipped the monster tutorial without really thinking about it because I was trying to save so I could turn off the Playstation and go to bed. Now I'm worried I missed something important. Is there a way for me to replay it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reread them in the datalog primers. (under combat if memory serves).
But for the thing during battle, I don't think you can unless you start a new game.